# creation of a symbol on pads

Tags: pcb, mentor-pads

I did simulations with the PA107 amplifier from Apex and now I want to go to the creation of PCB.

For the simulation I downloaded the lib of the amp and I created the symbol.
On the other hand for the creation of schema on PADS, the software that I will use for the creation of PCB, I can not put the amp on this software.

How could I do that?

Comment: Do you know how to create a footprint linked to a name in PADs? I think they may use the word decal (from memory). Do you know how to create a symbol for the schematic editor you are using? Can you also, when using the schematic editor, link the PCB footprint name to the schema part? If you can't do any of the above then you are probably asking the wrong question because learning how to do this relates to the creation of any part and, you should be using PADs source material and not relying on this site as a support group for mentorgraphic products.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to import the component, I downloaded the component lib for pads which is in the form of 3 files after I import these files on pads that's all